# How do I set a minimum margin distance between figures?

Tags: spacing, graphics, subcaption

This my setting

```
\begin{figure*}[t]  
 \begin{minipage}{.24\textwidth}        
 \centering         
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/1.png}   
 \subcaption{}      
 \label{1}  
 \end{minipage}\hfill   
 \begin{minipage}{.24\textwidth}    
 \centering     
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/2.png}   
 \subcaption{}  \label{fig:a} 
 \end{minipage}\hfill   
 \begin{minipage}{.24\textwidth}    
 \centering     
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/3.png}  
 \subcaption{}  
 \label{2} 
 \end{minipage}\hfill   
 \begin{minipage}{.24\textwidth}        
 \centering         
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/4.png}       
 \subcaption{}      
 \label{fig:b}  
 \end{minipage}\\[\baselineskip]    
 \begin{minipage}{.24\textwidth}    
 \centering     
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/5.png}  
 \subcaption{}  
 \label{3} 
 \end{minipage}\hfill   
 \begin{minipage}{.24\textwidth}    
 \centering     
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/6.png}   
 \subcaption{}  
 \label{fig:c} 
 \end{minipage}\hfill   
 \begin{minipage}{.24\textwidth}        
 \centering         
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/7.png} 
 \subcaption{}      
 \label{4}  
 \end{minipage}
 \hfill     
 \begin{minipage}{.24\textwidth}    
 \centering     
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/8.png}   
 \subcaption{}  
 \label{fig:d} 
 \end{minipage}\\[\baselineskip]    
 \begin{minipage}{.24\textwidth}    
 \centering     
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/9.png}  
 \subcaption{}  
 \label{5} 
 \end{minipage}\hfill   
 \begin{minipage}{.24\textwidth}        
 \centering         
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/10.png}          
 \subcaption{}      
 \label{fig:e}  
 \end{minipage}\hfill   
 \begin{minipage}{.24\textwidth}    
 \centering     
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/11.png} 
 \subcaption{}  
 \label{6} 
 \end{minipage}
 \hfill     
 \begin{minipage}{.24\textwidth}    
 \centering     
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/12.png}      
 \subcaption{}  
 \label{fig:f} 
 \end{minipage}\\[\baselineskip]    
 \begin{minipage}{.24\textwidth}    
 \centering     
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/13.png} 
 \subcaption{}  
 \label{7} 
 \end{minipage}\hfill   
 \begin{minipage}{.24\textwidth}        
 \centering         
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/14.png}          
 \subcaption{}      
 \label{fig:g}  
 \end{minipage}\hfill   
 \begin{minipage}{.24\textwidth}    
 \centering     
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/15.png} 
 \subcaption{}  
 \label{8} 
 \end{minipage}\hfill   
 \begin{minipage}{.24\textwidth}    
 \centering     
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/16.png}      
 \subcaption{}  
 \label{fig:h} 
 \end{minipage}     
 \caption{Snapshots.}       
 \label{fig:snap} 
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the graphic you've posted on the basis of the code you've posted. Importantly, I get **16**, not 8, lettered subcaptions. Please tell us which document class you load and which graphic-related packages you employ.

Comment: By the way: All 16 `\centering` instructions are redundant and should be omitted to reduce code clutter.

Comment: The space above and below the captions are given by `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` (usually 0pt).  I prefer subcaptions to be closer to the row above than the row below, so i usually add a `\par\vskip\floatsep` between rows.

Comment: Thank you so much for all. @Mico has a right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're using the `subcaption` package. If that's the case, you can reduce the vertical distance between the graphs and the subcaptions via suitable `\captionsetup` directives, as is done in the following example.

I would also replace the 16 `minipage` environments with `subfigure` environments. Doing so enables a better use of the `\caption` and `\captionsetup` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document

\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=0.333\baselineskip} 
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0.1\baselineskip} % default is '1\baselineskip'

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[t]  
    \begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/1.png}
      \caption{}\label{1}   
    \end{subfigure}\hfill   
    \begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}    
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/2.png}   
      \caption{}\label{fig:a} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfill   
    \begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/3.png}
      \caption{}\label{2} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfill   
    \begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}        
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/4.png} 
      \caption{}\label{fig:b}   
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \medskip % or, \bigskip if you want more vertical whitespace
    \begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/5.png}
      \caption{}\label{3} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfill   
    \begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/6.png}   
      \caption{}\label{fig:c} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfill   
    \begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}        
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/7.png}
      \caption{}\label{4}   
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill  
    \begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/8.png}   
      \caption{}\label{fig:d} 
    \end{subfigure}
        
    \medskip % or, \bigskip if you want more vertical whitespace
    \begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/9.png}
      \caption{}\label{5} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfill   
    \begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}        
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/10.png} 
      \caption{}\label{fig:e}   
    \end{subfigure}\hfill   
    \begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/11.png}
      \caption{}\label{6} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill  
    \begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/12.png}      
      \caption{}\label{fig:f} 
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \medskip % or, \bigskip if you want more vertical whitespace
    \begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/13.png}
      \caption{}\label{7} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfill   
    \begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}        
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/14.png} 
      \caption{}\label{fig:g}   
    \end{subfigure}\hfill   
    \begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/15.png}
      \caption{}\label{8} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfill   
    \begin{subfigure}{.24\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/16.png}      
      \caption{}\label{fig:h} 
    \end{subfigure}     
\caption{Snapshots.}
\label{fig:snap} 
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: To place pairs of graphics into `subfigure` environments, simply provide 2 `\includegraphics` statements per `subfigure`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document

\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0.2\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/1.png}%
      \hfill
      \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/2.png}    
      \caption{\dots}\label{fig:a} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfill   
    \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/3.png}%
      \hfill    
      \includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/4.png} 
      \caption{\dots}\label{fig:b}  
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \medskip % or, \bigskip if you want more vertical whitespace
    \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=.475\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/5.png}%
      \hfill
      \includegraphics[width=.475\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/6.png}    
      \caption{\dots}\label{fig:c} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfill   
    \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}        
      \includegraphics[width=.475\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/7.png}%
      \hfill
      \includegraphics[width=.475\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/8.png}    
      \caption{\dots}\label{fig:d} 
    \end{subfigure}
        
    \medskip % or, \bigskip if you want more vertical whitespace
    \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=.475\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/9.png}%
      \hfill        
      \includegraphics[width=.475\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/10.png} 
      \caption{\dots}\label{fig:e}  
    \end{subfigure}\hfill   
    \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=.475\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/11.png}%
      \hfill
      \includegraphics[width=.475\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/12.png}   
      \caption{\dots}\label{fig:f} 
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \medskip % or, \bigskip if you want more vertical whitespace
    \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=.475\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/13.png}%
      \hfill        
      \includegraphics[width=.475\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/14.png} 
      \caption{\dots}\label{fig:g}  
    \end{subfigure}\hfill   
    \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=.475\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/15.png}%
      \hfill
      \includegraphics[width=.475\textwidth, height=3cm]{figs/16.png}   
      \caption{\dots}\label{fig:h} 
    \end{subfigure}     
\caption{Snapshots.}
\label{fig:snap} 
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is as I wanted but how to remove three dots (...) that appeared after the subcaption. Please help me. @Mico

Comment: @REDHWAN - Just remove the `\dots` instructions.

Comment: I replaced \medskip by \smallskip.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `\\[baselineskip]` with an empty line already reduces the space below the subcaptions quite significantly. If you want even less space above and below the subcaptions, you could use `\captionsetup[subfigure]` and adjust the values of `aboveskip` and `belowskip` to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t] 
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}                
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/1.png}     
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}         
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/2.png}   
    \subcaption{}  
    \label{fig:a} 
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}       
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/3.png}  
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}               
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/4.png}       
    \subcaption{}      
    \label{fig:b}  
  \end{subfigure}
    
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}      
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/5.png}  
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}      
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/6.png}   
    \subcaption{}  
    \label{fig:c} 
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}             
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/7.png} 
  \end{subfigure}\hfill     
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}        
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/8.png}   
    \subcaption{}  
    \label{fig:d} 
  \end{subfigure}
  
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}     
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/9.png}  
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}              
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/10.png}          
    \subcaption{}      
    \label{fig:e}  
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}       
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/11.png} 
  \end{subfigure}\hfill     
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}         
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/12.png}      
    \subcaption{}  
    \label{fig:f} 
  \end{subfigure}
   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}         
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/13.png}  
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}                
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/14.png}          
    \subcaption{}      
    \label{fig:g}  
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}         
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/15.png} 
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}         
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/16.png}      
    \subcaption{}  
    \label{fig:h} 
  \end{subfigure}     
  \caption{Snapshots.}       
  \label{fig:snap} 
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[t] 
\captionsetup[subfigure]{aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}  
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}                
      \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/1.png}     
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}         
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/2.png}   
    \subcaption{}  
    \label{fig:a} 
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}       
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/3.png}  
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}               
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/4.png}       
    \subcaption{}      
    \label{fig:b}  
  \end{subfigure}
    
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}      
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/5.png}  
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}      
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/6.png}   
    \subcaption{}  
    \label{fig:c} 
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}             
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/7.png} 
  \end{subfigure}\hfill     
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}        
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/8.png}   
    \subcaption{}  
    \label{fig:d} 
  \end{subfigure}
  
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}     
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/9.png}  
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}              
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/10.png}          
    \subcaption{}      
    \label{fig:e}  
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}       
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/11.png} 
  \end{subfigure}\hfill     
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}         
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/12.png}      
    \subcaption{}  
    \label{fig:f} 
  \end{subfigure}
   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}         
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/13.png}  
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}                
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/14.png}          
    \subcaption{}      
    \label{fig:g}  
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}         
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/15.png} 
  \end{subfigure}\hfill   
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.24\textwidth}         
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, height=3.cm]{figs/16.png}      
    \subcaption{}  
    \label{fig:h} 
  \end{subfigure}     
  \caption{Snapshots.}       
  \label{fig:snap} 
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @leandriis

Comment: As you see, subcaption was for the two images  under the second one as a, b, …, etc. Could I put them between them?. For example, subcaption (a)  put under hfill instead of second one.  Is it available or not? Similar fig 14 in this paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0921889019302891